# Do I need to recycle web server after modifying hgrc?

Tags: iis-7, mercurial

I have setup a Mercurial website in IIS7 using this tutorial:

http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows

I am slowly figuring out all of the options that I can tweak for the served repositories.  But I'd like to know if and when I need to recycle the website process in order to pick up changes made to any of the repositories' hgrc files?  Does the website pick up the changes on the next request or do I need to always recycle?

Additionally, do I need to "restart" the website or run iisreset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - hgweb is CGI code, which is executed on every request.

Changes made to hgrc files will take effect immediately, no restarts required.